# how to remove worthless tags from jsf f:selectItem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I will create a list with checkbox. Anything like gmail mail box. I use `h:selectManyCheckbox` , `f:selectItem` in  HTML `table` tag. But jsf tags, itselft create a table and destruct my form. How can id say to jsf tags that just create `input` tag not anymore?
the following is a peace of my code:

```
<tbody>
    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{MemberControl.selectedUser}">
    <c:forEach items="#{MemberSearchControl.members}" var="member" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td><f:selectItem itemValue="#{member.id}"></f:selectItem> </td>
        <td><span>#{member.lastName}</span></td>
        <td><span>#{member.firstName}</span></td>
        <td><span>#{member.shareCount}</span></td>
        <td><span>#{member.phone}</span></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>  
</tbody>
```

And in the following you can see the result:

[image]

Do you have any solution for move checkbox in its correct place? (I use pure jsf not primefaces or any more)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectManyCheckbox.html). Your attempt to fix this makes absolutely no sense. The `<c:forEach><f:selectItem>` should just be a `<f:selectItems>` and you should be using a custom renderer for the job. Tomahawk has already done it before for you, its [`<t:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectManyCheckbox.html) with `layout="spread"` attribute set, along with `<t:checkbox>` components declared at the desired places, allows you to control the markup fully:

```
<!-- This piece renders _nothing_. -->
<t:selectManyCheckbox id="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItems}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</t:selectManyCheckbox>

<!-- You can markup those the way you want. They solely render <input>. -->
<t:checkbox for="foo" index="0" />
<t:checkbox for="foo" index="1" />
<t:checkbox for="foo" index="2" />
<t:checkbox for="foo" index="3" />
...
```

An alternative is to just fix your CSS styles. It look too much like that you overgeneralized `table`, `tr`, `td`, etc styles to be applied on *all* of those elements instead of only those by a specific style class such as `table.datatable` for `<h:dataTable styleClass="datatable">`.